# 'tick' is not working in c3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

My code is :

```
var object : _id: 1408991400000, a: 0 ,b: 11, c: 0 ,d: 65;
```

Here ,_id is a timestamp

```
var dataObject=array of object

                var chart = c3.generate({
                    bindto: '#container',
                    data: {
                        json: dataObject,
                        keys: {
                            x:'_id',
                            value: ['a', 'b','c','d'],
                        },
                    axis : {
                        x : {
                            type : 'timeseries',
                            tick: {
                                format: function (x) {
                                  console.log(x);
                                    var d = new Date(parseInt(x));
                                    var curr_day = d.getDate();
                                    var curr_month = d.getMonth();
                                    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
                                    return curr_day+'-'+parseInt(curr_month)+(1)+'-'+curr_year;
                                }
                            }                                    
                        }
                    }

                    }
                });
```

I am able to plot the above graph but I am not able to format the timestamp. Also when I try to log into console ,I dont get any output.Please let me know the mistake.

Comment: @MohitArora : Even though :this http://jsfiddle.net/k9Dbf/9/ works fine . My code is almost similar to it but still not working . What can be the mistake?

Comment: can you share your website url? are you using same c3.js version? try to replace file from jsfiddle example

Comment: @MohitArora : Im working on localhost. Ok ,would try to replace the c3.js version.

Comment: @MohitArora : I changed the library, still the same issue.

Comment: did you try with static data as in jsfiddler example?

Comment: @MohitArora Yeah , I tried with static data too . Still the same issue ,tick is not working.

Comment: @MohitArora :Hey what is wrong with this : http://jsfiddle.net/k9Dbf/13/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k9Dbf/15/

Comment: @MohitArora : Thx , i was making a mistake in the syntax. My axis was inside the data.

Comment: yea now its working on localhost?